# How to query mongodb dynamically with interface{}

Tags: mongodb, go

Am trying to make a dynamic mongodb query using a Go interface as shown bellow

```
func (m *NfInstanceDataAccess) FindIp(preferredNfInstances string, args ...interface{}) ([]model.NfProfile, bool) {
    var ip []model.NfProfile
    pipeline := bson.M{"nfType": preferredNfInstances, "allowedNssais.sst": args, "allowedNssais.sd": args}
    filter := bson.M{"ipv4Addresses": true}
    err := db.C(COLLECTION).Find(pipeline).Select(filter).All(&ip)
    if err != nil {
        return ip, false
    }
    return ip, true
}
```

There is no error when I use the function in my http server handler as

```
    nfInstanceIp, success := Da.FindIp(targetNfType, sst, sd)
            if !success {
                WriteError(response, ErrInternalServer)
                return
            }
```

but the response nfInstanceIp is always empty even though there values in my mongodb collection that matches the FindIp arguments. 
When I use other types like integer and string as in below code, everything work.

```
func (m *NfInstanceDataAccess) FindIp(preferredNfInstances string, sst int, sd string) ([]model.NfProfile, bool) {
    var ip []model.NfProfile
    pipeline := bson.M{"nfType": preferredNfInstances, "allowedNssais.sst": sst, "allowedNssais.sd": sd}
    filter := bson.M{"ipv4Addresses": true}
    err := db.C(COLLECTION).Find(pipeline).Select(filter).All(&ip)
    if err != nil {
        return ip, false
    }
    return ip, true
}
```

Can anyone explain to me the reason why the use of interface is not working and how to write this function dynamically?

Modifying the function as suggested to use mongodb $or logic like the code below

```
func (m *NfInstanceDataAccess) FindIp(preferredNfInstances string, args ...interface{}) ([]model.NfProfile, bool) {
    var ip []model.NfProfile
    pipeline := bson.M{
        "nfType": preferredNfInstances,
        "$or": []interface{}{
            bson.M{"sNssais.sst": args[0].(int32), "sNssais.sd": args[1].(string)},
            bson.M{"amfInfo.taiList.tac": args},
            bson.M{"smfInfo.taiList.tac": args},
            bson.M{"upfInfo.taiList.tac": args},
        },
    }
    filter := bson.M{"ipv4Addresses": true}
    err := db.C(COLLECTION).Find(pipeline).Select(filter).All(&ip)
    if err != nil {
        return ip, false
    }
    return ip, true
}
```

The logical $or does not work. Its only work when my FindIp input matches

```
bson.M{"sNssais.sst": args[0].(int32), "sNssais.sd": args[1].(string)}
```

but other inputs do not work even if set the type casting to the args
Any idea how i can use the mongodb logical $or in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **perform the indexing** and if required do the **type casting** as well.

```
pipeline := bson.M{"nfType": preferredNfInstances, "allowedNssais.sst": args[0].(int), "allowedNssais.sd": args[1].(string)}
```

OR

```
pipeline := bson.M{"nfType": preferredNfInstances, "allowedNssais.sst": args[0], "allowedNssais.sd": args[1]}
```